# Adding framework to project and another framework

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, static-libraries, static-linking

I spent on this issue all my time and now is out of ideas, so decided to ask for an advice.
I have project, that use framework (internally developed). They both use Firebase. Previously Firebase was added to project via pods, but now it doesnt work as needed, unfortunately, and to keep things working I need to add it statically to the project.
Project -> use framework (internally developed), so framework doesnt have back link to project (and it is correct). If to add Firebase statically to this framework, it doesnt initialise properly cause GoogleService-Info.plist locates in project, and run script code that initialise Firebase I added to the project, but at this stage it cant link with Firebase static library, that locates inside those framework (internally developed). Move GoogleService-Info.plist and run script to framework (internally developed) is not ok, cause this framework uses in other projects.
So I decided to create one more framework, that will statically contain all needed Firebase files and Firebase.h file and add it to project and framework (internally developed) separately. But everytime I face some errors. Could anyone advice how to make it correct? I havent found any link with similar issue.
Any help and advice is appreciated.
[image]

Edit:
Here is structure
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @shallowThought I updated my question. Ir looks like I am not correctly setting up all the frameworks between themselves

Comment: @shallowThought I cant set header search path, cause Firebase is a separate framework, and it is outside SCROOT file path. I dont know how to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, you do not link the mSDKPersisfance target with LocalFirebase.

1. Select the mSDKPersistance target
2. Add LocalFirebase.framework to the "link with library" Build Phase

Comment: could you please help me with linking issue?

Comment: Your question is too brought and the information is not enough. Edit your scheme to build dependencies in the correct order and do not do am magic (parallel build, find dependencies)